# C++ homework how to

Tags: c++, void

Hello I need help with program,

> data : a = 8,5,0 , f=4,0,8 , m=0,2,4

where is 0 i need to count this with a formula : a = f/m
so here is my code:

```
//Antrasis Niutono desnis
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
  //---------------------
void Odpowiedzi(int & a,int & f,int & m);
//---------------------
const char read[] = "duomenys1.txt";
const char result[] = "rezultatai1.txt";
//---------------------
int main() {
    ifstream rd(read);
    ofstream rs(result);
    int n,a,f,m;
    rd >> n;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n;i++) {
        rd >> a >> f >> m;
        Odpowiedzi(a,f,m);
        rs << a << "  " << f << "  " << m << endl;
    }
    rd.close();
    rs.close();
    return 0;
}
void Odpowiedzi(int & a,int & f,int & m)
{
    if(a=0 && f>0 && m>0)
        a=f/m;
    else if(f=0 && a>0 && m>0)
        f=m*a;
    else if(m=0 && a>0 && m>0)
        m=f/a;
}
```

Result must be a = 8,5,2 f=4,10,8 m= 0,2,4
But my result is a=0,0,0 f=0,0,0 m=0,0,0

Comment: Compiling with warnings enabled (or even better: with warnings as errors) would have given you the cause of the problem immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, the following is an assignment:

```
if(a=0 && f>0 && m>0)
    ^ THIS
```

It sets `a` to zero, and then treats that zero as a Boolean value (`false`) when evaluating the rest of the expression.

You meant to write:

```
if(a==0 && f>0 && m>0)
    ^^
```

This mistake is repeated in several places and explains why you're getting zeros.

It is a good idea to enable compiler warnings when building your code. This is one of those errors that a good compiler would have spotted and warned you about.